# Pop Up form during page loads

Tags: popup, css-float

I want to know how they make that pop up greeting during pages loads like on this wiredsystems page [wired systems website](http://www.wiredsystems.com/shopping/)

It is like a small form with a greeting on it.

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I figured, the popup starts when the page is fully loaded (I guess with the JS function ```onload()```)

Answer (score 0):

Following is the script from page source of that site. In short, you call a pop-up function  with $(document).ready.

```
require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/jquery.cookie'
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
                    if($("body").hasClass("cms-index-index")) {
                        var check_cookie = $.cookie('newsletter_popup');
                if(window.location!=window.parent.location){
                    $('#newsletter_popup').remove();
                } else {
                    if(check_cookie == null || check_cookie == 'shown') {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            beginNewsletterForm();
                        }, 1500);
                    }
                    $('#newsletter_popup_dont_show_again').on('change', function(){
                        if($(this).length){        
                            var check_cookie = $.cookie('newsletter_popup');
                            if(check_cookie == null || check_cookie == 'shown') {
                                $.cookie('newsletter_popup','dontshowitagain');            
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $.cookie('newsletter_popup','shown');
                                beginNewsletterForm();
                            }
                        } else {
                            $.cookie('newsletter_popup','shown');
                        }
                    });
                }
                    }
                });

        function beginNewsletterForm() {
            $.fancybox({
                'padding': '0px',
                'autoScale': true,
                'transitionIn': 'fade',
                'transitionOut': 'fade',
                'type': 'inline',
                'href': '#newsletter_popup',
                'onComplete': function() {
                    $.cookie('newsletter_popup', 'shown');
                },
                'tpl': { 
                    closeBtn: '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close fancybox-newsletter-close" href="javascript:;"></a>' 
                },
                'helpers': {
                    overlay: {
                        locked: false
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#newsletter_popup').trigger('click');
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help KZee.

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as answer. Thanks.